# Error when trying to print a 2 dimensional array(Matrix)

Tags: java, arrays

An error occurs at line 10 saying something about long. But I don't understand why I am getting such an error since int can also be taken as arguments. Also, if it's a duplicate question kindly send a link to the original question.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrix {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int[][] matrix = Matrix.matrixCreator();
    for(int p = 0; p < matrix.length; p++) {
        for(int o = 0; o < matrix[p].length; o++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix[p][o]));
 }
    }
}

public static int[][] matrixCreator() {
    int[][] matrix = new int[3][3];
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] convertToInt = new int[3];

    for(int position = 1; position <= matrix.length; position++) {
        System.out.printf("Enter the elements of the matrix in row %d separating them with spaces: " , position);
        convertToInt[0] = scan.nextInt();
        convertToInt[1] = scan.nextInt();
        convertToInt[2] = scan.nextInt();

    matrix[position - 1] = convertToInt;
    }
    return matrix;
}
}
```

The error it shows is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
    The method toString(long[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (ints)

    at Matrix.main(Matrix.java:10)
```

Comment: Please post code. We **cannot** help without you at least posting some code.

Comment: What is the actual error, could you paste the stack trace... To get an answer that could help you, check the [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ok, I'll try editing it

Comment: You need to post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "Arrays.toString(...)" actually, you need to pass an array, not an int.

For Example

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix[p]));
```

In your case, the matrix is a two-dimensional array. If it was a three dimensional then this will work.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix[p][o]));
```

Since the return of "matrix[p][o]" is going to be a single-dimensional array.

Comment: Thank you, I actually forgot it's a value and not an array I'm passing

Comment: But is there any other way to print the matrix since passing just the array will return the hashcode and if using Arrays it doesn't drop the brackets

Comment: for(int p = 0; p < matrix.length; p++) {
        for(int o = 0; o < matrix[p].length; o++) {
    System.out.print(matrix[p][o] + " ");
 }System.out.println();
    }

Comment: You just pointed out that matrix[p][o] is not an array and therefore returns an error

Comment: hey i have updated it. Check again. We are not using Arrays.toString()

Comment: I've seen it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must not use the cell alone but you should use one full single dimensional array as input for `Arrays.toString`. You do not need the inner loop also in the given code.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix[p]));
```

If you are using a double loop, using Arrays.toString is just an overkill. You can simply use the following in that case.

```
System.out.println(matrix[p][o]);
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. Though the brackets which I'm trying to get  rid of still remains